# I would like to stream live h264 video to HTML5 video tag, what kind of headers and container do I need?

Tags: html, video, streaming, h.264

I have a program that is running a server and what I would like to do is to stream video from it.  I have the video stream coming in one frame at a time in H264 format and would like to stream it out, to be picked up by a HTML5 video tag.  Cross browser support it not necessary as it is just a proof of concept demo, any browser is acceptable. A requirement of this project is that it needs to be H264.

So I tried just sending these headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Thu, 09 Jan 2014 17:28:14 GMT
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:video/quicktime

Correct headers?

Followed by raw h264 packets but of course it didn't seem to work and I believe I need to wrap it in a container format.  I understand I can use quicktime, mp4, or matroska.  Any recommendations for which one to use and how to go about encoding it into one of those containers?

Thoughts in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard video tag does not have support for any live formats. The only exception is safari supports HLS in the video tag on Mac and iOS.

UPDATE: This answer is a bit old now. MSE provides a way, But it it not as simple as adding a "src" unless you use something like video.js or mediaelement.js

Comment: Appearently I accidentally hit submit then took longer than the allowed 5 minutes to edit the comment.

Here's what I meant to say:
Thanks again szatmary, you answered last time I asked a similar question :)

Is it easily possible to pretend that you are loading a file, only not actually have a file there and essentially simulate loading it from file while actually sending it live video?  or not really?

Comment: Actually.. for anyone in the future who stumbles across this, it seems possible in Chrome, especially since I believe the media source API mentioned here is no longer experimental:  http://www.smartjava.org/content/face-detection-using-html5-javascript-webrtc-websockets-jetty-and-javacvopencv

Comment: Media source API is definitely the future. But currently you must use chrome. If that is ok, then my answer is correct also, just use safari. These theoretical questions are impossible to answer, because there is an infinite number of solutions, and I don't know what is and is not acceptable to you (It doesn't need to be cross browser, but you never say what browsers are acceptable, Or is it the OS that is the problem? I am left to guess) This solution meets all your requirements as stated in the question, but it doesn't meet your actual non stated requirements.

Comment: Any browser works fine.. just proof of concept demo on any browser.

Oh, and I didn't realize that hls supports h264.. so correct answer but still doesn't completely solve the problem.. unless you know of a library that can translate h264 frames into HLS or some other format?  I believe RTSP was preferred but not required.

Comment: HLS only supports h.264. ffmpeg (libavformat) will do AVC annexB to HLS. Just to be clear, I don't think safari on Windows will do hls, just OSX and iOS